# NPM install - variant

Tags: npm

Just out of curiosity is there a good reason why NPM has an isntall method like so:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2933

> To reiterate the official position on this: working as designed. npm is not here to punish people for spelling mistakes. npm is here to install your packages, even if you type "isntall".

Comment: all I can say is this is woefully inconsistent on more than one level. none of the other commands allow for spelling mistakes - also I think you meant typing mistake since I really doubt most people would misspell "install" as "isntall", you know what I sayin' g?

Comment: @AlexMills In the "you know what I'm saying" spirit... "who cares?" Install's probably the most commonly used command, and it probably got added because a few NPM devs got tired of making the mistake.

Comment: eh, I think it's bad practice frankly but that's only an opinion and just one opinion at that